# Not able to install mesos on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mesos, mesosphere

Following the instructions at:

https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/

Install mesos package gives the following error:

```
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -y install mesos
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mesos
```

Yes, the registry is configured:

```
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 

hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E56151BF
Executing: /tmp/tmp.EkBvspzAIM/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
E56151BF
gpg: requesting key E56151BF from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E56151BF: "Mesosphere Archive Automatic Signing Key <support@mesosphere.io>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ DISTRO=$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ CODENAME=$(lsb_release -cs)
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ 
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ # Add the repository
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ echo "deb http://repos.mesosphere.com/${DISTRO} ${CODENAME} main" | \
>   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list
deb http://repos.mesosphere.com/ubuntu xenial main
arun@arun-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -y update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [93.3 kB]   
Hit:4 http://repos.mesosphere.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Fetched 185 kB in 1s (117 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://repos.mesosphere.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 81026D0004C44CF7EF55ADF8DF7D54CBE56151BF uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

What's missing?

Comment: Follow the "Getting Started" instructions at http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/.  However, before building from source (running "../configure" from the build directory), make sure you also install libz with "sudo apt install zlib1g-dev" (from http://askubuntu.com/questions/792851/apache-mesos-install-missing-libz).  That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The mesos packages for Ubuntu 16.04 are not yet released. They should be available soon.

Comment: any chance you know about the python issue during installation of mesos on ubuntu 16.04 lts?  the __init__.py file is missing - do you know anything about that issue?